# Arduino read get values after ? in url with ethernet shield

Tags: get, arduino, rgb, ethernet, led

Sorry if it has been asked before but I cannot find anything on the internet. I just want to host a page in arduino ethernet shield and when I visit it from a browser with Get parameters (e.g http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/led.html?red=255,green=0,blue=255) to change to change the led's color. I cannot find how to send data from browser to arduino.

Comment: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetBegin have you tried this? to establish the connection that is.

Comment: This is to initialize the shield. How could I use it to parse values?

Comment: I was just determining whether or not you've established a connection to your gateway DHCP first. As far as resolving requests to the device goes, I'm sure it - like any other ethernet card or periphal device - does not perform web server functionality..

Comment: Yes I know the basics but how can I parse values from browser to arduino (I prefer by get parameters)

Comment: yes.. it seems you can, if you embed a web server in ardunio. you'll find this information helpful: http://www.academia.edu/7510788/Embedded_Web_Server_using_Arduino_Ethernet_Shield

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to read the get values? Because I cannot find anything relative in the page you told me

Answer (score 0):

The answer involves the use of [The Ethernet Library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) (**Ethernet.h**) - which provides an interface to [`Client`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConstructor) and [`Server`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServerAvailable), a degree of conceptualizing low-level I/O and buffering the input, and **context**.

In the following code snippet ( of the sample code at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer )

```
...
char c = client.read();
Serial.write(c);
...
```

the line `char c = client.read()` is taking a byte from the request stream and assigning it to a char type, it is then serialing that charbyte to a string where it perform conditional logic on it.

The conditional logic of that sample only cares about reading whether a return character `\n` on a blank line, but the bytes that are being read (on each iteration) byte to byte, actually compose the RAW Request.

At minimal, a RAW HTTP GET Request looks like this:

```
GET /?first=John&Last=Doe HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost
```

So, for you to read the query string, you'll need to **buffer** the bytes being read from the stream.

Then, you'll likely serialize the whole buffer into a string, and perform string operations on them, as well as your conditional logic....